# Setting cookies in WP REST API requests

Tags: cookies, rest-api

I'm trying to use `setcookie` inside a WP REST request, but it isn't working. The REST request runs properly and performs it's other duties well, but it doesn't set any cookies.

Here's my example code, which is running on `mywebsite.com`

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'my_auth/v1', '/auth_login', array(
        'methods' => array('POST'),
        'callback' => 'auth_login',
    ));

});


function auth_login( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    update_post_meta(1234, 'test_field', 'test_value'); // this works!
    setcookie('auth_token', 'test1234', time()+3600, "/", 'mywebsite.com'); // this doesn't work
    return 'test';
}
```

If I send an AJAX request to my endpoint (`mywebsite.com/wp-json/my_auth/v1/auth_login`), the `update_post_meta` call works fine, but the `setcookie` call does not. I have tested this by visiting `mywebsite.com` after a request, which has no cookies set.

Comment: Do you see the `set-cookie` directive in the return headers from the rest call?

Comment: @GentlemanMax Yes! They are there in the Response Headers: `Set-Cookie:auth_token=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx; expires=Fri, 06-Jan-2017 18:08:37 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mywebsite.com` - but they don't get set.

Comment: Hmm, is this a cross domain request?  If so then you might be running up against a [CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801021/what-can-cause-a-cookie-not-to-be-set-on-the-client) issue.

Comment: @GentlemanMax yeah, it is cross-domain. I'm building a particularly tricky single sign-on implementation for a client. I've learnt that setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in my headers may work - giving that a try now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line to my `$.ajax` call fixed the problem for me.

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    // the rest...
```

Sidenote: this requires the following header to be set on the server-side, which is enabled by default with the REST API (it seems).

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to your ajax call:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: plus I don't think that adds anything to Rory's answer?